# How to convert timestamp to a string(php)?

Tags: laravel-5

I use laravel as my php framework. In my database, I have a `create_at` field that is created with `timestamp()`. I use the databse:query builder to get this field, which is not a simple string.

How can I convert this to a simple string, such as `2016-07-08 22:09:08`?

I use `''.$variable->create_at` before.

Comment: The answer could be found with a simple search before asking the question here. Use `date` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi there what i usually do is use carbon to output my date string so in your view you would use something like this

```
{{$variable->created_at->diffForHumans ()}}
```